# Renderer for ColumnTree?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to add a custom renderer to a ColumnTree in Ext JS. Since it appears(?) that this isn't supported, does anyone know of any workaround to use a renderer? Here's a snippet of code - let's just say (hypothetically) that I have a renderer I'd like to use for the documentsVersion tab below - does anyone have any ideas?

```
return new Ext.tree.ColumnTree({
    autoHeight: false,
    rootVisible: showRoot,
    autoScroll: false,
    id: (!treeId)? window.mainTreeId: treeId,
    loader: (!loader)?window.docTreeLoader:loader,
    columns: [{
         header:"${documentsTitle}",
         width: windowWidth * 0.40
     },
     {
         header:"${documentsVersion}",
         width: windowWidth * 0.10,
         dataIndex:'version'
     },
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from this [ExtJS forum post](http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=20793) they still evaluate `renderer` column property in their `ColumnNodeUI.js` subclass for rendering column data.

So you may try to add `renderer` property along with `header`, `width` and `dataIndex`.

Comment: I did try this (as I didn't want to waste everyone's time prior to asking) without much success. It could likely be a problem with what I'm doing with the renderer, although the renderer does work elsewhere (using same renderer I use for a Grid Column). I'll poke around with it, thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you should use an inline renderer function (anonymous function) in this case ?